# CreateProcessAsUser returns C0000142 in one scenario, but works in another

Tags: c#, winapi, wix, impersonation, wix3

We have a problem which only occurs in a new scenario we have to support.

Here's the scenario in which it works since many years:

- An interactive user without administrative permissions starts our wix bootstrapper, which starts our `update-service` which then starts a second instance of the wix bootstrapper as `local system`. This second instance with `local system` permissions is used to install our software. Because we have to do some database stuff too, we execute a tool called `dbinit` within a custom action and because this tool has to access a sql server, it has to run under the origin user privileges. **This works fine.**

[image]

- Now there's an additional scenario we have to support: It's not an interactive user anymore, who starts our wix bootstrapper, now it's a windows service. I thought this would be pretty straightforward and should work out of the box, but ohhh boy, was I wrong. Here's the sequence diagram of the new scenario:

[image]

As you can see, in the new scenario, `CreateProcessAsUser` also succeeds, but the `dbinit`-process then immediately exits with error code `C0000142`.

We tried creating custom `WindowStation`/`Desktop`. The permissions should be correct (checked with `ProcessHacker`) and we also marked the handles as `inheritable`. But regardless they are `inheritable` or we set `lpDesktop` accordingly, it just doesn't change anything.

What we found out is, if the user under which the windows service is running is in the local administrator group, it works, but we can't do that in production.

In many code samples I found people are using `LogonUser` to get the token, but because our user is a MSA (Managed Service Account) most of the time and we don't have passwords, I don't think that's possible.

## UPDATE 1:

If I set `lpDesktop` to an empty string, it works in about 50 % of the cases so it seems, that it has to do something with `WindowStation` and `Desktop`. What I don't get is, why it does not work consistently and why it doesn't help to create custom `WindowStation` and `Desktop` with proper rights.

## UPDATE 2:

Some code:

```cs
internal static SafeTokenHandle GetProcessAccessToken(int processId)
{
    var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
    if (OpenProcessToken(process.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out IntPtr tokenHandle))
        return new SafeTokenHandle(tokenHandle);
    else
        throw new Win32Exception();
}

internal static SafeTokenHandle DuplicateAccessToken(SafeTokenHandle token)
{
    var success = DuplicateTokenEx(token,
                                    TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,
                                    null,
                                    IMPERSONATION_LEVEL_SecurityIdentification,
                                    TOKEN_TYPE_TokenPrimary,
                                    out IntPtr newToken);


    return success ? new SafeTokenHandle(newToken) : throw new Win32Exception();
}

private bool Start()
{
    using (var processToken = GetProcessAccessToken(StartInfo.ProcessIdToImpersonateUserContext))
    {
        using (var newToken = DuplicateAccessToken(processToken))
        {
            var si = new STARTUPINFO();
            var pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            var safeProcessHandle = new SafeProcessHandle();
            var safeThreadHandle = new SafeThreadHandle();

            SafeFileHandle redirectedStandardOutputParentHandle = null;

            try
            {
                var profileInfo = new PROFILEINFO();
                profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                profileInfo.lpUserName = "LimitedUser";

                var succeeded = LoadUserProfile(newToken, ref profileInfo);
                if (!succeeded)
                    throw new Win32Exception();

                var cmdLine = $"\"{StartInfo.FileName}\" {StartInfo.Arguments}".Trim();

                if (StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
                {
                    CreatePipe(out redirectedStandardOutputParentHandle, out si.hStdOutput);
                    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
                }

                int creationFlags = 0;
                if (StartInfo.CreateNoWindow)
                    creationFlags |= CREATE_NO_WINDOW;

                creationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;

                int logonFlags = 0;
                if (StartInfo.LoadUserProfile)
                    logonFlags |= (int)LogonFlags.LOGON_WITH_PROFILE;

                string workingDirectory = StartInfo.WorkingDirectory;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
                    workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                var envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(newToken);

                succeeded = CreateProcessAsUserW(newToken,
                                                    null,
                                                    cmdLine,
                                                    null,
                                                    null,
                                                    true,
                                                    creationFlags,
                                                    new HandleRef(null, envBlock.DangerousGetHandle()),
                                                    workingDirectory,
                                                    si,
                                                    pi);

                if (!succeeded)
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                if (pi.hProcess != (IntPtr)0 && pi.hProcess != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    safeProcessHandle.InitialSetHandle(pi.hProcess);
                if (pi.hThread != (IntPtr)0 && pi.hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    safeThreadHandle.InitialSetHandle(pi.hThread);

                DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock.DangerousGetHandle());
            }
            finally
            {
                si.Dispose();
            }

            if (StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
            {
                var enc = StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding ?? Console.OutputEncoding;
                StandardOutput = new StreamReader(new FileStream(redirectedStandardOutputParentHandle, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false), enc, true, 4096);
            }

            _processHandle = safeProcessHandle;

            safeThreadHandle.Dispose();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you haven't looked up the error, it's symbolic constant is `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`.

Comment: C0000142 = STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED, meaning dbinit is failing to load/iniitialize a DLL. Try running your scenario either with Process Explorer or windbg to figure out what's failing.

Comment: start your process (*dbinit *) in suspended state. look for it token. check in what is different in both case. attach debugger. look which call is failed. frequently this is `NtGdiInit`

Comment: 0xC0000142 STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED :{DLL Initialization Failed} Initialization of the dynamic link library %hs failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

I suggest you could try to add LoadUserProfile. When a user logs on interactively, the system automatically loads the user's profile. If a service or an application impersonates a user, the system does not load the user's profile. Therefore, the service or application should load the user's profile with LoadUserProfile.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thanks for your tip, but we already tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [What is up with "The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142)" error?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/what-is-up-with-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0000142-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We still don't know exactly, why Windows in our scenario is always using `winsta0\default`, but we think it has something to do with `rundll32` being involved.

The reason why setting `lpDesktop` to a custom `WindowStation` and `Desktop` never worked is, that we mixed up `Ansi` and `Unicode`. As soon as we set `CharSet` explicitly to `Unicode`, it worked. Here's the code:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal class STARTUPINFO
{
    public int cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    ...
}

[DllImport(ADVAPI32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
internal extern static bool CreateProcessAsUser(SafeHandle hToken, string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine,
                                                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles,
                                                int dwCreationFlags, HandleRef lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
                                                PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

Our solution now works as follow:

- If the process, where we take and duplicate the token from, runs in session 0, we create a custom `WindowStation` and `Desktop`, so we don't run into permission issues.
- If the process does **not** run in session 0, we leave everything as it was and ran for years, because then it uses `winsta0\default` which is perfectly fine, because the user of the interactive process seems to have proper permissions.

Comment: I have a very similar issue to yours, although I am using LogonAsUser before CreateProcessAsUser. I am encountering an issue where my process runs correctly if the user targeting with LogonAsUser is Admin, but I get C0000142 if my user is not admin (which I want). It almost seems as if I need to give my non admin user a permission to access the winsta0\default desktop, but I'm not sure how.